# Python Unit Testing - 'gcsfs.utils.HttpError: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.'

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, google-cloud-storage, python-unittest

I'm running a Python unit test on this script `api.py`

```
def download_models(gcs_model_path, local_path):
    filesystem = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=PROJECT)  # , token='creds.json')
    # download models from gcs
    filesystem.get(gcs_model_path, local_path, recursive=True)
```

Here is the unit test script `embedding_api_test.py`

```
class EmbeddingAPITest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('gcsfs.GCSFileSystem')
    def test_download_models(self, mock_filesystem):
        mock_filesystem.return_value.get.return_value = []
        download_models('gcs_model_path', 'local_path')
```

I'm getting this error on my terminal:

```
_______________________ ERROR collecting qa_api/tests/qa_api_test.py ________________________
qa_api/tests/qa_api_test.py:3: in <module>
    from qa_api.api import app
qa_api/api.py:37: in <module>
    download_models(GCS_MODEL_PATH, LOCAL_MODEL_PATH)
qa_api/api.py:21: in download_models
    filesystem.get(gcs_model_path, local_path, recursive=True)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py:556: in get
    rpaths = self.find(rpath)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py:371: in find
    for path, dirs, files in self.walk(path, maxdepth, **kwargs):
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py:326: in walk
    listing = self.ls(path, detail=True, **kwargs)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py:767: in ls
    out = self._list_objects(path)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py:571: in _list_objects
    items, prefixes = self._do_list_objects(path)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py:604: in _do_list_objects
    maxResults=max_results,
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py:504: in _call
    raise e
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py:487: in _call
    validate_response(r, path)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py:130: in validate_response
    raise HttpError(error)
E   gcsfs.utils.HttpError: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

It seems I'm mocking it incorrectly but I don't understand why. Would really appreciate any help. Please let me know if more details are required. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should patch `'api.gcsfs.GCSFileSystem'`. E.g.

`api.py`:

```py
import gcsfs

PROJECT = "teresa.teng"


def download_models(gcs_model_path, local_path):
    filesystem = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=PROJECT)
    filesystem.get(gcs_model_path, local_path, recursive=True)
```

`test_api.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from api import download_models


class EmbeddingAPITest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('api.gcsfs.GCSFileSystem')
    def test_download_models(self, mock_filesystem):
        mock_filesystem.return_value.get.return_value = []
        download_models('gcs_model_path', 'local_path')
        mock_filesystem.assert_called_once_with(project="teresa.teng")
        mock_filesystem.return_value.get.assert_called_once_with('gcs_model_path', 'local_path', recursive=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                     Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/64673419/api.py            5      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/64673419/test_api.py      11      0   100%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                       16      0   100%
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
gcsfs==0.7.1
```